# Need a way to output merged content from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two very large arrays I want to recognize where it finds duplicates on the first array, and merges them with the exact array position in another array, and append the value with a comma. I simply cannot wrap my head around how to do it.

```
//array with the multiple entries.
$applicationid = array('1','1','2','3','3','4','5','6','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','13','14','14','15','16','17','18','18');
$applicantid = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','11','22','25');
```

Easily viewed it looks like this when put side by side.

```
applicationid on left.  applicantid on right.
    1   1
    1   2
    2   3
    3   4
    3   5
    4   6
    5   7
    6   8
    6   9
    7   10
    8   11
    9   12
    10  13
    11  14
    12  15
    13  16
    13  17
    14  18
    14  19
    15  20
    16  21
    17  11
    18  22
    18  25
```

I would like the end result to be for these two arrays:

```
[1]['1,2']
[2]['3']
[3]['4,5']
[4]['6']
[5]['7']
[6]['8,9']
[7]['10']
[8]['11']
[9]['12']
[10]['13']
[11]['14']
[12]['15']
[13]['16,17']
[14]['18,19']
[15]['20']
[16]['21']
[17]['11']
[18]['22,25']
```

I'm sure this is easy for someone out there but I cannot seem to be able to wrap my head around it or understand the syntax required.

Additionally just to note the arrays are much bigger than this (roughly 1400 or so entries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. That's very convenient that indexes match (whilst it says that the data is generated in a not very suitable format).

Try merging them like this:

```
$applicationid = array('1','1','2','3','3','4','5','6','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','13','14','14','15','16','17','18','18');
$applicantid = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','11','22','25');

$applicantsByApplications = [];
$applicantsCount = count($applicationid);
for ($i = 0; $i < $applicantsCount; $i++)
{
    $applicant = $applicantid[$i];
    $application = $applicationid[$i];
    if (!isset($applicantsByApplications[$application]))
        $applicantsByApplications[$application] = [];
    $applicantsByApplications[$application][] = $applicant;
}
```

This can be beautified using standard functions, `array_map` etc., but the principle stays the same.

Comment: your output not expected output

Comment: Sorry, didn't check the code with PHP runtime :-(
Now all is fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately but so close!  The output still keeps the initial digits despite whether or not there is a duplicate entry.

Comment: @sblumberg Strange... I get the same output as your expected one. See here http://shorttext.com/81e3dac

Comment: Thank you very much that worked.  Now to figure out some nested while loops to get it to output what I need to.  Sorry for seeming so nooby at this I am still learning a lot!

Comment: @sblumberg Thanks for an interesting problem to solve. Enjoy your programming journey ;-)